# Creating new onclick method with passed in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I currently popup a bootstrap dialog to ensure that the user wants to delete someone. When that user says ok, I need to pass the value that came in to the function along to the actual delete method. Currently everything I have tried has passed along 'undefined' as the variable.

```
function RemoveTeamMember(peoplePK) {

//First remove all old click events(so we can reuse), and re-initialize the modal with our new info
$("#ConfirmationDialog #ConfirmationOKButton").off('onclick');
$("#ConfirmationDialog .modal-header .modal-title").text("Remove Team Member?");
$("#ConfirmationDialog #ConfirmationText").addClass('text-danger').text("Are you sure you want to remove this team member?");
$("#ConfirmationDialog #ConfirmationOKButton").html("Remove Member");

//$("#ConfirmationDialog #ConfirmationOKButton").prop("onclick", "PerformRemoveTeamMember(" + peoplePK + ")");
//Bind the new click event for the ok button
//$("#ConfirmationDialog #ConfirmationOKButton").bind('click', { param: peoplePK }, PerformRemoveTeamMember);
$("#ConfirmationDialog #ConfirmationOKButton").data("pid", ''+peoplePK+'');
$("#ConfirmationDialog #ConfirmationOKButton").on('click', function () {
    //PerformRemoveTeamMember($(this).data("pid"));
    alert($(this).data("pid"));
});
$("#ConfirmationDialog").modal({
    show: true
});
}
```

Ultimately I need to attach a new onclick attribute to the button with the value of the peoplePK variable and this dialog will get reused between multiple operations. Which is why I must build this button dynamically.

EDIT: Added how RemoveTeamMember is called

```
'<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="RemoveTeamMember(' + row[0] + ');">Remove Member</button>';`
```

Answer: Changed how RemoveTeamMember is called
After a change this morning to how the datatables were formed, row[0], no longer gave the correct data as it was previously, this was changed to

```
'<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="RemoveTeamMember(' + data + ');">Remove Member</button>'
```

And this fixes the issue completely.

Comment: Do you think we have enough information to answer your question?

Comment: how is RemoveTeamMember called? You might be sending in an undefined variable

Comment: @Patrick-Evans 'RemoveTeamMember' is called by a button that is built dynamically as well. it is built like this. 
` '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="RemoveTeamMember(' + row[0] + ');">Remove Member</button>';`

I have checked that the value is passed in correctly

Comment: @Echofiend you aren't delegating event here, try instead, to test it: `$(document).on('click', "#ConfirmationOKButton", function () {...});`

Comment: To Clarify, the 'PerformRemoveTeamMember' method gets called correctly. However, the value that I need to pass in becomes 'undefined'

Comment: @Echofiend So you mean `row[0]` isn't defined but where/how do you define it?

Comment: It is from jquery.datatables and using the way that the tables WERE formed this was tested and the variable was coming through correctly. HOWEVER, it was changed this morning, and i need to change `row[0]` to `data` and it now passes through correctly. 
Thanks @Patrick-Evans for having me check this again. I will update my question